# XmlReader returns 500 error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use the XmlReader function. I am able to print the version number of my asp.net framework which is 4.0. As soon as I add the following line of code my server returns a 500 error.

```
<script runat="server">
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("myfeedUrl");
</script>
```

I set up visual studio on my computer and am now getting the error: "declaration expected".
After researching this new error I still have not come up with a solution to the problem, the XMLReader returning a 500 level error in the browser and the Declaration Expected error when compiling in visual studio.

Comment: 500 error is so called 'internal server error'. It does not say what wen't wrong, just that some error happened on server. Try accessing the server from `localhost` and see if IIS gives you more error information, or read about logging and tracing in IIS web server. IIS does not give more details than saying 500 error because it can be dangerous for visitors to know details of what is going on on your server.

Comment: The error I am getting is as follows "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" I have no idea what that means.

Comment: You are using ODBC to connect to database. It's possible that you are trying to use 32-bit ODBC connection in a 64-bit application (or the other way around). In 64-bit Windows you can create 32-bit and 64-bit DSNs. To connect to 32-bit driver use `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`, to connect to 64-bit driver use `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`. [Read more on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am now getting the error Declaration Expected.

Comment: Welcome to programming!  Getting a different error than the one you got previously is usually a good thing.  After you overcome them all you will be done.  Once in a while you'll write a whole bunch of code, and it will compile and run flawlessly.  Savor those moments.

Comment: Purpose of StackOverflow questions is not to get a task finished, but to find a solution to a specific technical problem. For further problems ask another question and provide more details other than "Declaration Expected".

Comment: Your information did not help me solve the problem, this is just the new error I receive when compiling the code using visual studio express. Declaration Expected is also the only information the error is giving me other than the error code itself (BC30188). It was my intent to update my current problem with the new error information to see if that would help in the solving of that single line of code not working.